# Zoom in image effect on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to make sure that when user hover over the image, it zooms in but does not go beyond the container/border.

just like on this [site](https://www.alpvisionresidences.com).

```
.thumbnail {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;    
}

.image img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; 
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; 
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease; 
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; 
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); 
  -moz-transform:scale(1.25); 
  -ms-transform:scale(1.25); 
  -o-transform:scale(1.25); 
   transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

I used it like this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to your `.image`